# How to monitor a java console application?

Tags: java

I want to ensure that a java console application is running fine 24/7. It is just a plain jar, no application server involved.

The things I want to monitor externally should be:

- the console app is actually running
- the database connection is alive
- any webservice connections are alive (the app is mainly a soap client)
- some statistics on eg CPU
- cron jobs are running

There are several servlet applications that provide those metrics when running on an application server. But what about my case where it's just a cmd application? How could I expose those tasks to external tools?

Comment: I generally use Monit to check on running services. YMMV.

Comment: logging what you want to know..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Jetty to allow your app to serve up a status page on demand? Or some JSON if you want it parseable by some other service?

Comment: I would not like to introduce a webserver dependency for just monitoring purpose, and I don't need one for any other task within my application. Regarding JSON status response, yes that would be an option. But at least I'd have to start an embedded jetty for this, right?